# Density of $C_c(X)$ in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

**1)** If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdofrf space, then $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$; $\mu$ it is the measure obtained by the Riesz representation theorem.

**2)** Suppose that $X$ not is locally compact, and let $\mu$ be a arbitrary measure in $X$.

**My question is:** Under the assumptions of 2), 1) is false?

Comment: Take $X = \mathbb R$ with trivial topology and $\mu$ the Lebesque measure. Then $C_c(X)$ is one dimensional and is not even in $L^p(\mu)$ for $p <\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a less trivial example than the one proposed by John's comment, let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and let $\mu$ be any nontrivial Borel measure on $X$ (a point mass will work).  By [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), every ball of $X$ contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence, hence is not contained in any compact set.  In other words, every compact set has empty interior.  Now for any continuous function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x : f(x) \ne 0\}$ is open and contained in the support of $f$.  So if $f$ has compact support, $\{x : f(x) \ne 0\}$ is empty; that is, $f \equiv 0$.  So in this case $C_c(X) = \{0\}$ which is certainly not dense in $L^p(\mu)$ if $L^p(\mu)$ has at least one nonzero function.